# Is List<System.Type> that accepts only certain types possible?

Tags: c#

is there any possibility to have a generic `List<System.Type>` and to have a constraint on the type?
I want to store types in a list for a lookup, but only types where the class of this type implements a specific interface.

Something like this:

```
List<Type> : where typeof(Type) is IMyClass
```

Is that possible? If not do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Any help appreciated !

**EDIT:**

Sorry I haven't been clearer on the subject, but Sign's comment below is correct, I don't have instances available, just types.

Assume the following:

```
class PluginA : IPlugin { } 
class PluginB : IPlugin { } 
class PluginC : ISomeOtherInterface { } 

var pluginTypes = new List<Type>()
pluginTypes.Add(typeof(PluginA) --> OK
pluginTypes.Add(typeof(PluginB) --> OK
pluginTypes.Add(typeof(PluginC) --> should fail
```

Yes I could wrap this, but hoped that there would be a better variant which checks during compiletime or hints with intellisense what types are allowed.

Comment: Why not use `List<IMyClass>` ?

Comment: Funny that a moderator would post an answer as a comment.  +1 anyways.  Also never understood the reason people phrase they answers as "Why not just do such and such".  Usually my response is, because I didn't know I could do that, which is obviously why I am here in the first place.

Comment: I think he means he wants a `List<Type>` where the contents is limited to type instances of types that implement `IMyClass`

Comment: @AaronLS not really... Understanding why that doesn't suffice may be key to proving the most suitable answer. It is a request for clarification, not an answer.

Comment: See, I'm reading this as if he wants to store `Type`, as in metadata, but only for classes with the common ancestor.

Comment: @MarcGravell you are saying that `List<String> test = new List<String>();
            test.Add(typeof(String));` is valid.

Comment: @Sign and Anthony: Yes that's exactly my issue. I have edited my question and added a hopefully better explanation...

Comment: Ah, I did indeed misinterpret the question. It is clearer with the edit.

Comment: @Sven: The type composition is nicely handled in MEF. If you're building a composition container for your plugins, you should take a look at it before rolling your own framework solution....

Comment: @code4life: Thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at it

Comment: @Sven: no problems :D  I've been using MEF for a bit now and have to admit it has solved many of the problems like the kind you just described. The MEF composition container does a fantastic job of collecting plug ins, even from disparate, unreferenced DLLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, you want a list of System.Type which checks that its elements implement a certain interface. This is easy to accomplish. Just implement `IList<Type>` by wrapping most the `List<Type>` functionality and add a couple of checkups.

```
public class TypeFilteredList : IList<Type>
{
    private Type filterType;
    private List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

    public TypeFilteredList(Type filterType)
    {
        this.filterType = filterType;
    }

    private void CheckType(Type item)
    {
        if (item != null && !filterType.IsAssignableFrom(item))
            throw new ArgumentException("item");
    }

    public void Add(Type item)
    {
        CheckType(item);
        types.Add(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Type item)
    {
        CheckType(item);
        types.Insert(index, item);
    }
```

...

```
}
```

this code will work for base classes as well as interfaces.

Example usage:

```
TypeFilteredList list = new TypeFilteredList(typeof(IInterface));
list.Add(typeof(Implementation));
list.Add(typeof(int)); // ArgumentException
```

If you however don't need `IList` functionality, you can implement `IEnumerable<Type>` or `ISet<Type>` (wrapping `HashSet<T>`). List leaves an option to add the same type several times, which it seems to me is something, you don't want.

Comment: +1 It's a shame you have to implement all of IList to achieve this but since all constraints do would say T was Type and not what subset of classes the Type represents...

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, I decided for this solution, but it was a close one between this and Viacheslav Smityukh's answer ..

Answer (score 5):

Well you could write your own wrapper:

```
public class ConstrainedList<T> where T : IMyClass
{
    private List<T> list;

    // Access the list however you want
}
```

You can't add constraints to `List<T>` itself though.

You *might* want to expose the wrapped list directly, or you might want to implement `IList<T>` and just delegate each member to the list. It's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I normally wouldn't do this (the answer is so trivial), but as nobody has suggested the most obvious answer...  Inheritance.

```
public sealed class IMyClassList : List<IMyClass> { }
```

Done and done.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any type for the `List`, so yes:

```
List<IMyClass> myClassList = new List<IMyClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using generics like this:

```
 class EmployeeList<T> where T : IMyClass
 {
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - make it a `List<IMyClass>` then you can store any instance that implements that interface.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one way to check it at compile time.
You can create class derived from the List and write custom generic Add method to do it.

Something like this:

```
class PlugginsList : List<Type>
{
  public void Add<T>()
    where T : IPlugin
  {
    Add(typeof(T));
  }
}

var plugginList = new PlugginsList();
plugginList.Add<PluginA>() --> OK
plugginList.Add<PluginB>() --> OK
plugginList.Add<PluginC>() --> will fail
```

You will achive all your goals by using generic method i.e. compile time time checkings, intellisense and all other type cheking tools provided by Visual Studio and C# compiler

Comment: This solution is of course possible and compile time checking is nice. But it still leaves an option to call Add and Insert (non-generic), where incorrect types might be added.

Comment: This is just a sample to show how to add strong type cheking to solve a current task.