# List which accept only few types

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Does there exist in any System namespace in C#  a container, which can accept only some types?
For example I want to create my list in which I'll have only objects with type Class1 and int:

```
//accept only type Class1 and int;
MYLIST lst = new MYLIST(typeof(Class1), typeof(int));
lst.Add( 23 ); // OK
lst.Add( new Class1() ); // OK
lst.Add( "text" ); // wrong, not accepted type
```

Is something like that in .NET or I have to write it on my own? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want static type checking for this?

Comment: I doubt that this construct would be generally useful, in fact I cannot think of a single use case - what are you trying to achieve? (And no, no such container exists in .NET)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535961/is-listtype-that-accepts-only-certain-types-possible

Comment: you should create a function for adding objects to list , so you can filter what is added and what is not

Comment: You probably need to write a wrapper.

Comment: I would ask the question why do you need to store the two types in the first place?  Why not unify the two type possibilities under a single class?  You're storing these values/instances for some reason, create a class for that reason which could hold a `Class1` instance or an `int` and be done with it.

Comment: I'm out of here, the OP doesn't care at all about the answers, and the childish attitude of people giving crappy answers drives me mad. I got better stuff to do. For the record: losing strong typing and casting in and out does not constitute a reasonable solution. **There ARE ways to keep strong typing and refrain from casting** but anyway, the only reason i can see for why I'd need such a collection is bad design. I'd redo the design and forget about it. Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO, there is NO such list in C# and for VERY GOOD reason.

You could make a wrapper, but i'd advise against it.

```
 public class CustomListWrapper< T, F>
    {
        private readonly List<object> internalList;
        public CustomListWrapper()
        {
            this.internalList = new List<object>();
        }

        public void Add(object item)
        {
            if(!(item is T || item is F))
                throw new Exception();

            this.Add(item);
        }

    }
```

PS: before the downvote, for how to get the object out...well this is why this is a fairly bad idea, but you'd have to do an "is" on the type you get out to be able to cast it to the proper type.

Again, not exactly sure why you would EVER need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The C# type system does not allow you to express something like "either `Class1` or `int`". Having said that, you can use overloads to get half of the way there:

```
class MyClass
{
    private List<object> _items = new List<object>();
    public void Add(int value) { _items.Add(value); }
    public void Add(Class1 value) { _items.Add(value); }
    ...
}
```

The real tricky question is how you get things *out*, rather than how you put things *in*. There are several possibilities: get everything out as `object` (by implementing `IEnumerable<object>`), and maybe special methods like `GetInt(int index)` and `GetClass1(int index)`.

Comment: -1: If he does that, he's going to have to cast every object back to its real type, making the caller aware of the intricacies of the collection.

Comment: @Baboon He could use `GetInt(42)` to either get the `int` stored at index 42 without casting, or an exception if there’s no `int` at that index. This is as close as one can get to what the OP is asking about. It’s possible the OP doesn’t actually _want_ what he’s asking about, but that’s a separate consideration.

Comment: Where is `GetInt`? besides, I'd be surprised if it didn't do any casting.

Comment: @Baboon, that is a very presumptuous down vote. You could easily attach meta data about the list item in many ways. You could have two lists internally, one of each type, for example.  And given the example given in the OP, he is likely going to have to cast outside of the list anyways.  I think your downvotes were unwarranted.

Comment: @NeilN I understand you're mad at being downvoted. You also conveniently disregarded the fact that this one implementation might not be the only possibility. Now as for "presumptuous", I'm just gonna guess you don't know what it means.

Comment: @Baboon, based on your response, I gather you did not understand my response at all.

Comment: The biggest drawbacks about this answer is that you loose all the advantages of having a public list.  What about enumerating the list items? what about adding and removing items from the list? We don't know why the OP needs a list, but I'm pretty sure OP would want to enumerate through the items in it.  Now, you could certainly add those interfaces to this class, and in some circumstances, that actually me advantageous (think of the Flyweight pattern; you'd still need a Flyweight class/interface, though).  These things were not mentioned in the answer I see.

Comment: @JayC as discussed in the last paragraph, this is not a complete answer because the OP didn’t post a complete question. He asks how to make it so you can *add* only the correct type. The rest is unspecified. I briefly mention how one might go about the rest, but enumerating every possibility is too much work; if the OP asks more specifically I’ll answer more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this in a direct way. The item type of a `List<T>` must be a base type common to all the types you want to add to the list.

You could have a `List<object>` or a wrapper around a `List<object>` of cause. However, you would have to check at runtime if the items added to it are of the correct types and you would have to cast the items that you retrieve from the list to the correct type.

If you want to store different types in the same list, a good option would be to create an interface that all of these types must implement

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
    int Number { get; }
    string Text { get; }
}

public Class1 : ICommonInterface
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string AnAdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}

public NumberWrapper : ICommonInterface
{
    public NumberWrapper (int number)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Text = number.ToString();
    }

    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
}

public TextWrapper : ICommonInterface
{
    public TextWrapper (string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        int i;
        Int32.TryParse(text, out i);
        this.Number = i;
    }

    public int Number { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can declare your list as

```
List<ICommonInterface> lst = new List<ICommonInterface>();
lst.Add(new Class1());
lst.Add(new NumberWrapper(77));
lst.Add(new TextWrapper("hello"));

Console.WriteLine(lst[0].Text);
```

Comment: -1 That's only one type - from OP's example, this misses the addition of `int`s.

Comment: `lst.Add(23);` will fail, though

Comment: I revised my answer, in order to address the question more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have to create your own. You can implement ICollection or IEnumerable or IList or whatever. You have lots of flexibility here. But bottom line, the answer is no, no such collection exists that allows you to limit the types in the collection to certain types automatically.

Answer (score 0):

why not just wrap a List<>, and make two add methods, one that accepts int, another that accepts Class1

Comment: -1: same reason as [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9927792/677014)